# Different behaviour of collapsible elements in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

I am working on an open source event management project and ran across a cross-browser problem. Here is the [event site](https://princu7.github.io/eventSiteWebApp/rooms.html)

**On Chrome**

On the rooms page, if I click on any session, it expands correctly and then collapses correctly on clicking again. Here are the screenshots:

On Clicking the session element (In this case 'Opening Speech')
[image: On clicking the session element]

On Clicking Again to collapse
[image]

**On Firefox**

On Clicking any session element(it expands normally)
[image]

But it **doesn't collapse correctly**. It creates an empty space. (only first session of the page collapse correctly)
[image]

I have tried to debug the error using the Developer console Window to no avail. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have inspected this in Firefox, and for some reason, Firefox won't pickup the sizes of the rows...

So I applied

```
.room-filter{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
}
```

to the rows with the drop down, which seemed to work!

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer. But can you please explain or give an idea regarding why it didn't work earlier and why did it started to work after adding in the required properties. Would be a great to know how did you come up with additional properties which fixed the problem. Thanks!!

Comment: I've been looking into this and I suspect the issue could be down to the fact that you have divs as child elements of h4.

I'd recommend using a div to wrap this section of markup instead of using h4.

Please see http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have been banging my head all day to find the reason for this bug. What I have found is that it has something to do with the float property of the div element. The parent element collapses because of the floated elements inside it and its height becomes zero. I looked up on the internet and the properties which you specified can be used to prevent the parent element from collapsing. I tried using the other properties which can be also used to prevent collapsing and all of them seemed to work. 

But still why does it happen? Please look into it. Thanks You